# Jolt Customer Transformer a Spring Bean

Tags: spring-boot, jolt

I have a spring boot application and i am using custom jolt transformer as below in my jolt spec.

```
  {
    "operation": "com.transformers.CustomJoltTransformer"
  },
```

The CustomJoltTransformer.java is a Spring Bean. Is there any way to pass this spring bean directly to jolt instead of Jolt creating bean for me? I have defined it as `@component as its i need to load the value of user from application.yml based on the different profile.

```
@Component
public class CustomJoltTransformer implements Transform {

@Value("${app.user}")
private String user;

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

@Override
public Object transform(Object input) {
    Map inputMap = (Map) input;
    ...
    inputMap.put("user", getUser());
    return inputMap;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`fromSpec` is overloaded method where you also have option to pass chainrInstantiator if you don't want to use default.

`Chainr.fromSpec(JsonUtils.classpathToList(path), chainrInstantiator)`

Here is my code for Custom Instantiator

```
@Component
public class CustomChainrInstantiator extends DefaultChainrInstantiator implements ChainrInstantiator {

    @Autowired
    private CustomJoltTransformer customJoltTransformer;

    @Override
    public JoltTransform hydrateTransform(ChainrEntry entry) {
        if ("CustomJoltTransformer".equalsIgnoreCase(entry.getJoltTransformClass().getSimpleName())) {
            return customJoltTransformer;
        }
        return super.hydrateTransform(entry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share entire code and spring boot configuration. In my case injected values are coming null in transformation